# React get value from State

Tags: reactjs, axios, webhooks

Complete beginner to React. I have a backend API that I am trying to send requests to using Axios. I have a box with numbers like so:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState(0);
const [input2, setInput2] = useState(0);

        <div>
            <label htmlFor="num1">Number 1: </label>
                <input type="string" id="num1" name="num1" value={input} onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="num2">Number 2: </label>
            <input type="string" id="num2" name="num2"value={input2} onInput={e => setInput2(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
```

This captures any value in these inputs.

```
    console.log({input})
    console.log({input2})
```

Logging these values shows the integer I put in there. However, when I try to access these values in an Axios request, it all goes wrong.

```
    const response = await     axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/service/", {
            params: {
                num1: {input},
                num2: ({input2})
            }
        })
```

My back end throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{"input":0}"]
```

I would just like to pass the zero to my request param, is this possible? If so, how to achieve this? I have tried parsing it in various different ways but nothing works. The backend only takes a number in those parameters.

Best regards.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your variables in braces? `input` should work as expected without the `{ }`

Comment: Lol. that was an easy solution. It works now. Thanks DBS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your state in curly brackets. Where you write `{input}`, javascript automatically creates a new object `{input: inputValue}` instead of returning the value of your `input` variable.

Just change your code to this:

```
    const response = await     axios
    .get("http://localhost:8080/service/", {
        params: {
            num1: input,
            num2: input2
        }
    })
```